# Returning struct in a c function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have something like the folowing C code:

```
struct MyStruct MyFunction (something here)
{
    struct MyStruct data;

    //Some code here

    return data;
}
```

would the returning value be a reference or a copy of the memory block for data?
Should MyFunction return struct MyStruct* (with the corresponding memory allocation) instead of struct MyStruct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would return a copy.  C is a pass-by-value language.  Unless you specify that you are passing pointers around, structures get copied for assignments, return statements, and when used as function parameters.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as a reference in C.  So semantically speaking, you are returning a copy of the struct.  However, the compiler may optimise this.

You cannot return the address of a local variable, as it goes out of scope when the function returns.  You could return the address of something that you've just `malloc`-ed, but you'll need to make it clear that someone will need to `free` that pointer at some point.

Answer (score 1):

It is returned as copy. BTW, you should not return it's reference because it has automatic storage duration ( i.e., data resides on stack ).

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems with this (a function in a DLL returning a struct) and have investigated it. Returning a struct from a DLL to be used by people who might have a different compiler is not good practice, because of the following.

How this works depends on the implementation. Some implementations return small records in registers, but most get an invisible extra argument that points to a result struct in the local frame of the caller. On return, the pointer is used to copy data to the struct in the local frame of the caller. How this pointer is passed depends on the implementation again: as last argument, as first argument or as register.

As others said, returning references is not a good idea, as the struct you return might be in your local frame. I prefer functions that do not return such structs at all, but take a pointer to one and fill it up from inside the function.

Comment: If you are experiencing ABI incompatibility issues such as this, then you need to fix them, not try to work around them!

Comment: How would I fix an ABI? I don't write compilers.

Comment: I mean make sure your toolchains are compatible!  If you're working with two toolchains with incompatible ABIs, then the problem you describe will only be one of many problems.

Comment: That is not always possible. DLLs can be written with any compiler, and I don't have every possible compiler (in each possible version) around. My preferred solution works for every compiler I know, and even for non-C compilers (e.g. Delphi). And I very often access DLLs written in C or C++ from Delphi. That is no problem, except if they do things like return structs. IOW, it is one of very few problems.

Comment: IMO, hammering together two binaries that use different calling conventions is asking for trouble.

Comment: I assume you never programmed for Windows. In Windows, you use DLLs written by someone using some compiler. Windows is entirely made up of DLLs. This works remarkably well, if the exported functions follow certain conventions. Returning a struct is one of the things one should not do. I am not talking about calling conventions. These define a lot (order of passing, mangling, etc.) but seldom how structs are returned.